# SCSS - possible to debug with react or chrome?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, sass

I'm using sass (scss) with react and I've run into an issue using the `@debug` directive. With Rails the debug directive outputs to the console but with ReactJS (via cra) I'm not seeing it in the react console.

**Question**

How can I debug my scss files when compiling with webpack using ReactJS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Temporary Solution**

If you use `@error` then react will display webpack error output instead of the rendered page, this is a hacky solution but it works well enough.